# It is a way to modify an SQL Insert Script with SED Command in order to insert word DATE before date value?

Tags: regex, windows, bash, sed, sql-scripts

## Modifying SQL Scripts with SED Command

I would like to explain my task. I have been asked to modify many files with one command without alter the data. The core is to properly insert DATE_B values, since it would give us an error trying to insert this into MYTABLE, due to the fact we create DATE_B as DATE datatype.

### My Scripts

```
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, DATE_B) values (to_timestamp('2017-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),'2019-09-09');
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, DATE_B) values (to_timestamp('2018-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD'),'2021-09-09');
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, DATE_B) values (to_timestamp('2022-08-11','YYYY-MM-DD'),'2022-08-06');
```

I have to modify all DATE_B values in order to insert DATE before the value. What I mean is:

### Expected Scritps

```
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, DATE_B) values (to_timestamp('2017-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),DATE'2019-09-09');
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, DATE_B) values (to_timestamp('2018-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD'),DATE'2021-09-09');
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, DATE_B) values (to_timestamp('2022-08-11','YYYY-MM-DD'),DATE'2022-08-06');
```

My approach was to use REGEX in order to identify the single quote, year, dash, month, dash, day, dash, single quote... But if I do this I will substitute also my properly formatted to_timestamp values.

I found this command from GeekForGeeks useful since we catch the first letter and we enclose them with parenthesis.

```
$ echo "Welcome To The Geek Stuff" | sed 's/\(\b[A-Z]\)/\(\1\)/g'
```

Trying to approach my goal:

```
$ echo "Welcome To The Geek Stuff '2010-10-12' '1999-10-10'" | sed -E 's/(\b[A-Z])/DATE\1/g'
```

Using regex:

```
$ echo "Welcome To The Geek Stuff '2010-10-12' '1999-10-10'" | sed -E 's/'('\d{4}-)'/DATE\1/g'
$ echo "Welcome To The Geek Stuff" ,'1999-10-10' | sed 's/^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/'DATE\1'/g'
```

I also read about h, H subcommand of sed, but it is not clear enough for me to make it works.

I would appreciate if someone could explain how to properly implement sed h subcommand and how to properly use regex with sed in order to identify COMMA, single quote, year, dash, month, dash, day, dash, single quote. Save this and insert word DATE

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: Really good first question, but take it one step further and you may figure it out yourself! The sample data you provide doesn't match the problem you're trying to solve. I think `echo "Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, DATE_B) values (to_timestamp('2017-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),'2019-09-09');" | sed "s/),'/),DATE'/"` should give you a hint. You don't always need to use compliated regular expressions if your data is consistent AND allows a simple match. Good luck.

Comment: will *all* `INSERT` statements consist of *just* the 2 columns `DATE_A` and `DATE_B` and in the same order as displayed in the sample? or could you be dealing with a variable number of columns in the `INSERT` statement? or could the columns be provided in a different order?  If you could have different variations then please update the question with more sample `INSERT` statements demonistrating the variations (to include some `INSERT` statements that should not be modified, some `INSERT` statements that span multiple lines)

Comment: @shellter Thank you for hint. I already managed to get my approach to work. I'll put my successfully command as answer of my question. I would like you to give a look. Regards

Comment: @markp-fuso Thank you for your question. No, I have multiple files scripts with their own columns and statements. Indeed I'm dealing with a variable number of columns, but what I identify as a constant was the idea of a comma before the date as '####-##-##'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- the column name isn't important; what's important are strings of the form `'YYYY-MM-DD'`
- these strings can occur anywhere in the `values (...)` clause; this means ...
- we need to address strings at the beginning of the `values (...)` clause (ie, has a preceding `(`) as well as strings elsewhere in the `values(...)` clause (ie, has a preceding `,`) but ...
- also need to refrain from adding the `DATE` prefix if the string is embedded within a function (eg, `to_timestamp('YYYY-MM-DD')`)
- assume all `INSERT` statements are formatted as shown in the sample (eg, a space between `values` and `(`; no white space before a `'YYYY-MM-DD'` string)

Adding a few scenarios to our input:

```
$ cat insert.sql
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, DATE_B) values (to_timestamp('2017-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),'2019-09-09');
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, DATE_C) values ('2021-09-09',to_timestamp('2018-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD'));
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, MY_INT, DATE_B) values ('2022-08-11','2344','2022-08-06');
```

One `sed` idea:

```
sed -E "s/( \(|,)('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}')/\1DATE\2/g" insert.sql
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex support (eliminates need to escape parens and braces)
- `"s/..../g"` - wrap `sed` script in double quotes to eliminate need to escape single quote within the script
- `( \(|,)` - (1st capture group) space + `(` *or* a comma (in this case we need the escape to designate the `(` as part of the data)
- `('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}')` - (2nd capture group) our string `'YYYY-MM-DD'`
- `\1DATE\2` - inserting the `DATE` string between the two capture groups

This generates:

```
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, DATE_B) values (to_timestamp('2017-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),DATE'2019-09-09');
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, DATE_C) values (DATE'2021-09-09',to_timestamp('2018-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD'));
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_A, MY_INT, DATE_B) values (DATE'2022-08-11','2344',DATE'2022-08-06');
```

Once satisfied with the results OP can add the `-i` flag to have `sed` overwrite the  input file.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe next command properly achieve to identify if a comma is before a single quote and if then is follow by a date like 2019-09-09. In order to insert in between comma and first single quote the word DATE.

```
sed -i 's/,\'\([0-9]\{4\}\)\-\([0-9][0-9]\)\-\([0-9][0-9]\)\'/,DATE\'\1\-\2\-\3\'/g' test.sql
```